# How can I fix this code, for shaker sorting

Tags: python, typeerror

```
def cocktail_sort(seq: list):
    for i in range (len(list) -1, 0, -1):
        swapped = False
        for j in range(i, 0, -1):
            if list[j] < list[j-1]:
                temp = list[j]
                list[j] = list[j-1]
                list[j-1] = temp
                swapped = True
        for j in range(i):
            if list[j] > list[j+1]:
                temp2 = list[j]
                list[j] = list[j+1]
                list[j+1] = temp2
                swapped = True
            if not swapped:
                return list
lst = [15, 4, 7, 2, 1, 20]               
print(cocktail_sort(lst))
```

TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len()

I tried to find a solution to the problem on YouTube and forums, I sat several times and thought about what to do. I'm just a beginner and I don't really understand.

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Answer (score 1):

In your function header you have your argument written as `seq: list`. This means "I would like one input parameter called `seq` and it must be of type `list`".

However, inside your function, you are trying to use `list` to reference your input parameter. You should instead be using `seq` to reference your input parameter.

The error is basically saying "`list` is a type, not a variable" wherever you've tried to use `list`.

---

You don't necessarily need to specify a type in your function header, but if you would like to use the type hinting, I would recommend having a look at the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Answer (score 0):

You have accidentally (at the top) put `len(list)` instead of `len(seq)`